# In Rails, How can I convert params[:id] to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, casting

Guys I am trying to retrieve specific records from the DB using `params[:id]`.

```
 x = Authors.find(params[:id])
```

We cannot use **FIND** with string like this because the parameter is always passed by **HTTP** as a string:

I also tried this code but I do not know why it always returns **0** while the passed parameter is **4**

```
 x = Authors.find(params[:id]).to_i
```

So how can I do something like **casting for ID Parameter** or Any method to convert HTTP passed **strings to integers**

Comment: are you sure that params[:id] is not blank? You should be having any issue in fetching record using params[:id]. Rails actually takes care of that part.

Comment: @mandar.gokhale ...should NOT have...

Comment: Seems like an xy problem. Why would it be necessary to cast the ID? That's the question, not how best to cast it.

Comment: @ValAsensio .. Actually I have another parameter. It is passed form drop-down menu. Its value is "16" as a string as it appears in pry

Comment: @ValAsensio ... The passed parameter is "16" from this line `cat_id = params[:artCatName].to_i` but when checked the returned value after conversion, it is always 0

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to convert strings to integer to use find. It should be able to convert the string for you.

```
Just to give an example:
Author.find(2) # => #<Author:1234>
Author.find("2") # => #<Author:1234>
Author.find("2") == Author.find(2) # => true
```

Try using `pry` to see if what you are passing is correct. Hope this helps clear out the method.

Comment: I am using "pry". I tried tens of times to do many things. I don't understand what do you mean by this line: Author.find("2") == Author.find(2)

Comment: If you type it on console, it should return true because it should return the same object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have just misplaced your type casting:

```
x = Authors.find(params[:id].to_i)
```

Comment: Even this way is not working

Comment: Most likely `params[:id]` is null, then. If you're using strong params and short cutting that in someway then it's quite possible you haven't whitelisted `id`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
x = Authors.find(params[:id].to_i)
```

However,

```
x = Authors.find(params[:id])
```

is also correct as it returns the correct author.
Before using the above one you can check whether the params[:id] is present or not:

```
if params[:id].present?
  x = Authors.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: This is my code. Currently, I am sending another parameter which is CategroyID.....I could not convert it like this....`cat_id = params[:artCatName].to_i` by using "pry" I found the sent parameter is "16". But how to make it Integer

Comment: what is the datatype of `:artCatName` Is it string?

Comment: If it is an Integer then your method will produce the correct result..

Comment: this is the output from PRY `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"tQetEjfE+stm/yXfQWyS9pEhznu+zeNwrHPa6BNjWsfd4bcv/PFsYRcMT1L8y2obJt6xNTcoOFNgzq6R6OcjMw==",
 "category"=>{"artCatName"=>"1"},
 "article"=>{"artTitle"=>"bb", "artBody"=>"b"},
 "commit"=>"Publish",
 "controller"=>"articles",
 "action"=>"create"}`

Answer (score 0):

After I used the method **.inpect** on the parameter which I am trying to grab, I found that it was nil. I was grabbing it wrongly. By the way, I was trying to grab another parameter not **:id** but **:artCatNam**e and Here are my passed parameters:
`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tQetEjfE+stm/yXfQWyS9pEhznu+zeNwrHPa6BNjWsfd4bcv/PFsYRcMT‌​1L8y2obJt6xNTcoOFNgzq6R6OcjMw==", "category"=>{"artCatName"=>"1"}, "article"=>{"artTitle"=>"bb", "artBody"=>"b"}, "commit"=>"Publish", "controller"=>"articles", "action"=>"create"}`

Here how I grabbed **:artCatName** and how I converted to **integer**

```
params[:category][:artCatName].to_i
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you (repair numeric params converted into string):
https://gist.github.com/owen2345/1400e0ec5224a2e842ebd750d402133a